# Why does lsmod command show many modules with size of 16384

Tags: drivers, kernel

I run `sudo lsmod` command on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I get an output a section of which is shown below.

```
Module                  Size  Used by
simple_lkm             16384  0
ufs                    73728  0
xt_CHECKSUM            16384  1
iptable_mangle         16384  1
ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  3
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 24576  2 nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  2
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
xt_conntrack           16384  1
nf_conntrack           98304  5 nf_nat,nf_nat_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv4
ipt_REJECT             16384  2
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
xt_tcpudp              16384  6
bridge                114688  0
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 stp,bridge
ebtable_filter         16384  0
ebtables               24576  1 ebtable_filter
ip6table_filter        16384  0
ip6_tables             20480  1 ip6table_filter
iptable_filter         16384  1
ip_tables              20480  3 iptable_filter,iptable_mangle,iptable_nat
x_tables               24576  11 ip6table_filter,xt_CHECKSUM,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,ebtables,ipt_REJECT,iptable_mangle,ip6_tables
drbg                   28672  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
ctr                    16384  2
ccm                    20480  2
binfmt_misc            20480  1
gpio_ich               16384  0
dell_wmi               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
dell_rbtn              16384  0
dell_laptop            24576  0
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
dell_smm_hwmon         16384  0
nvidia              10375168  52
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             167936  0
kvm                   483328  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_codec_idt      53248  1
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_hda_codec         118784  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           61440  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
input_leds             16384  0
...
```

Now, I'm curious if there is any specific reason that the size of many modules is `16384`.

Comment: and why are they always an even number....  ;-)

Comment: .... likely the module builder program allocates/saves blocks of memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are not the size of modules, to get the real size of these modules you can run something like:

```
lsmod | grep 16384 | cut -f1 -d ' ' | xargs modinfo | grep filename |\
 grep -o '/.*' | xargs stat -c "%s - %n"
```

Which outputs (in bytes):

```
...
19086 - '/lib/modules/4.4.0-78-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi.ko'
21470 - '/lib/modules/4.4.0-78-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko'
15798 - '/lib/modules/4.4.0-78-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-dev
...
```

The "16384" is the size of memory used by that module in bytes which is equal to "16KiB". And as I know it's just a default number and also the minimum that can be used, if you look carefully you can see that there is no module with the size less than of 16384.

I guess this minimum is related to `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN`, run:

```
getconf PTHREAD_STACK_MIN
```

you will get:

```
16384
```

From [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstacksize.3.html):

> The stack size attribute determines the minimum size (in bytes) that will be allocated for threads created using the thread attributes object attr.

[read more](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setstack) and [more](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/topic/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/p/pthread_attr_setstack.html).